# Code to upload Video from Android to PHP

Tags: php, android, image-uploading

I am trying to upload video from Android code to my PHP web server code but can't get success. I am referring the following [link](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/) to perform the uploading task but I am getting the following response in my Android code, but can't found any file on PHP server.

Android response

```
DEBUG/ServerCode(29484): 200
DEBUG/serverResponseMessage(29484): OK
```

I have checked many things like setting values in `php.ini` files.
Although I can upload images from Android code to server becasue from Android I am sending a 64 bit encoded `ByteArray` and therer is a ready-made function in php which can create image from encoded `ByteArray`s.

But that code also is not working in case of any other file having type other than image.

Please guide me if any of you have done something similar before.

PHP code I am using:

```
<?php

    $target_path  = "./upload/";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
    {
        echo "The file ".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

Android code I am using:

```
public void videoUpload()
{
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;


    String pathToOurFile = "/sdcard/video-2010-03-07-15-40-57.3gp";
    String urlServer = "http://10.0.0.15/sampleWeb/handle_upload.php";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary");

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile );
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
     String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
     Log.d("ServerCode",""+serverResponseCode);
     Log.d("serverResponseMessage",""+serverResponseMessage);
    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you guarantee your php.ini is fine, then you did some mistake in your code. Post your code. The blog you followed seems fine, but you might have made some mistakes while 'following' that blog article.

Comment: Hi Sarwar i have updated the code here of both Android and PHP. Tried a lot but can't found problem in this small code

Comment: Abhishek, did u get any solution on uploading the video on server in android? I am also looking for same. If u have any idea then please share with me.

Comment: ya i have marked it as answered below, it solved the purpose and Videos getting uploaded fine through multipart form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My java is a bit ropey but....

It looks like connection.getResponseCode is returning only the HTTP status code, and connection.getResponseMessage is returning only the HTTP status message - but you're PHP does nothing to manipulate those values. You might try:

```
$target_path  = "./upload/";
$src = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

$target_path .= basename($src);

if(file_exists($src) 
        && 
        && move_uploaded_file($src, $target_path)
   ) {
    echo "The file ".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
} else {
    header("Server Error", true, 503);
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    $msg = "src size ? " 
       . filesize($src) . "\n dest dir writable ?"
       . is_writeable(dirname($target_path)) ? "Y\n" : "N\n"
       . "FILES contains :\n";
       . var_export($_FILES,true);
    // now write $msg somwhere you can read it
}
```

This shuld help in narrowing down what went wrong

Comment: thanks symcbean for the code are u confirm that last three lines of the code u provided are right syntax-wise .

Comment: by running this code also i am getting the same response 200 and OK

Answer (score 0):

```
private String mString;
private Uri image_uri;  
private String response;    
private HttpURLConnection conn = null;
private DataOutputStream dos = null;
private String lineEnd = "\r\n";
private String twoHyphens = "--";
private String boundary = "*****";
private int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
private byte[] buffer;
private String url_for_image_upload = "your_web_api_put_here";
private int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
```

//then call these two methods on button's onclick listener

mString = getRealPathFromURI(image_uri);

ImageUpload();

//write these methods here

```
private void ImageUpload() {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Please Wait while uploading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(mString));
        URL url = new URL(url_for_image_upload);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"img_name\";filename=\"img_name"
                + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        Log.d("BuffrerReader", "" + in);

        if (in != null) {
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
            Log.e("FINAL_RESPONSE-LENGTH",""+response.length());
            Log.e("FINAL_RESPONSE", response);
        }

        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

        if (response.startsWith("0")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Image Uploaded not successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Image Uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e("Image upload", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("Image upload", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }

}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    mString = cursor.getString(column_index);

    return mString;

}

public static String convertStreamToString(BufferedReader is)
        throws IOException {
    if (is != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {

            while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("");
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```