# Upload the video to the webservice

Tags: android

Here i am trying to upload the video to the webservice.Can anybody show me by some code.??
reply me soon.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hey i think this will help you [Code to upload Video from Android to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944650/code-to-upload-video-from-android-to-php)

You can also refer at this discussion in SO [Upload video from Android to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017093/upload-video-from-android-to-server)