# Capture video of applications from an Android device and upload

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails mobile application needs to capture the video from android and upload on the app.How to proceed this feature.Please help on this

Answer (score 2):

Learn about camera code from this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html
This has the source code for cam corder example  http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/mobilemedia_spring10/Camcorder.zip
and you can upload a video file using php 
[Code to upload Video from Android to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944650/code-to-upload-video-from-android-to-php)
http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-video-library-1259.html